# How to prove this Holder- type inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, holder-inequality

I don't understand why this inequality holds (i found it in some notes): Let $ v\in L^1 \cap C_c, $ then

$$ \Vert v\Vert_{L^{q}} \leq \Vert v\Vert_{L^{1}}^{\frac{1}{q}} \cdot \Vert v\Vert_{L^{\infty}}^{1-\frac{1}{q}}. $$

I think that this could be a "consequence" or a particular case of Holder inequality, but i don't know how to prove it. Can anyone please help me?

Moreover, it is necessary that $ v\in L^1 \cap C_c $ or i can suppose that $ v\in L^p \cap H^s, $ with $ 1\leq p\leq 2$ and $ s\geq 0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need any assumption on $v$ other than $v \in L^1 \cap L^{\infty}.$

Indeed:

$$\int |v|^q \leq \|v\|_{L^\infty}^{q-1} \int |v|.$$

Comment: Incredible easy, i'm sorry if haven't thought about this solution. Just another question: if i have $ v \in L^p \cap H^s, 1\leq p\leq, 2 $ i'm sure i can apply this inequality? i.e. i'm sure $ v\in L^1 \cap L^{\infty} $?

Comment: This depends on the value of $s$. The key word is Sobolev embedding, which gives: $H^s \subset C^{s {-} d/2}$ where $d$ is the dimension of the space (and the latter is the Holder spaces of regularity $2{-}d/2$).

Comment: To be honest, my problem is more specific. I have a function $ v\in L^p \cap H^{\left[\frac{n}{2}\right] + i +\alpha} , $ with $ 1\leq p\leq 2 $ and $ n $ denotes the dimension of $ R^n $. I need to apply the inequality i ask above but i'm not sure (as you suggested) that $ v\in L^1 \cap L^{\infty}$. Using the sobolev embedding that you said, i can say that $ H^{\left[\frac{n}{2}\right] + i +\alpha} \subset C^{\left[\frac{n}{2}\right] + i +\alpha -\frac{n}{2}}, $ but i am not sure that implies $ v\in L^1 \cap L^{\infty}$.

Comment: What is $i, \alpha$? If their sum is strictly positive and the integer approximation is from above and below, it means that the Holder regularity is strictly positive and thus the function is not only in $L^{\infty}$, but also continuos.